# Cheapest linux devices?

Tags: networking

I'm getting interested in ultra-cheap linux devices lately. So far I've been playing with some no-name "3G/4G router" devices from amazon (such as this $10 job [http://www.amazon.com/BrainyTrade-Mobile-Wireless-Hotspot-1800mAh/dp/B0093IPJKQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0093IPJKQ)), which runs OpenWRT and gives me USB and Wifi connectivity, and a battery, which charges off USB.

I'm curious what other ultra-cheap linux devices people are playing with?

Define ultra-cheap as <30USD.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest looking at the [raspberry pi](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CG8QFjAA&url=http://www.raspberrypi.org/&ei=aA1rUrWOAeGuiQKhxYGoAQ&usg=AFQjCNEBMoebclm0Gk0LCZIStJbF04U1cQ&sig2=Sg6shW1zT21vW3b_DSvMUw&bvm=bv.55123115,d.cGE):

I purchased one to play with a while back on ebay, it comes in under 30 bucks (but you'll need a sd card (you can get away with a small one if you also have a usb stick), and a power supply.)  
It runs a variety of linux distros, including a [variant](http://www.raspbian.org/) of debian with access to a wide variety of packages. 

Another great option are the WRT54Gs, which can be bought for a song on [craigslist](http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/?areaID=1&subAreaID=&query=wrt54g&catAbb=sss).  They are just old 'G' wireless routers, but can be flashed with openwrt or ddwrt-  I created a lot of interesting linux networking labs with this family of devices.

A third option, which depending on your negotiating prowess may fall just outside that 30 dollar barrier, are [DLINK's DNS-323 NAS boxes](http://dns323.kood.org/).  I love these things!  They quite hackable- you can [root the DLINK default firmware](http://dns323.kood.org/howto%3atelnet), install custom firmware called '[ALT-F](https://code.google.com/p/alt-f/)', and even install [debian](http://dns323.kood.org/howto%3ainstall_debian).  I've been able to score a few of these for 25 bucks a pop, and together they make a neat little server farm, with a lot of very useful functionality- and they are fairly power efficent to boot.
** I think my answer is more, what I found cheap but also interesting to play with- I'm sure there are other dirt cheap alternatives out there.

Oh, and I found [this](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) the other day, it's not a device itself- but instead linux running in a browser window- pretty amazing what hardware requirements have shrunken to in this case.